# How can we change the priority of jobs during Hive execution?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, hadoop-yarn

I had 2 jobs to finish on Hive cluster. The first one came first and will take a ton of time while the second one came later but needs almost immediately.

Since the first task is so data-heavy that it's expected that this will not finish overnight, so is there a way to switch the priority of tasks without killing the first one?

Answer (score 0):

If the second job requires data from the first, you should schedule the queries using a workflow engine like Oozie or Airflow.

Otherwise, unless the YARN cluster is completely overloaded, both jobs will be able to run in parallel